# Send files from Ubuntu to iPhone idevicepair says "no device found"

Tags: iphone, ubuntu-18.04, libimobiledevice

How to get idevicepair to see my iPhone?

I'm trying find some way of sending files to the phone from laptop without using Internet.

Following the instructions at https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/IOS for installing libimobiledevice:

1. systemctl status usbmuxd.service Yes it shows running since my last boot days ago
2. idevicepair pair: **no device found**

tail syslog shows a lot of errors on plugging in the phone but
lsusb lists the phone

Following instructions at https://opensource.com/article/21/8/libimobiledevice-iphone-linux:

1. ifuse --help to confirm libimobiledevice is installed: help displayed successfully
2. mkdir ~/iPhone ok
3. ifuse ~/iPhone: "**No device found**"
4. ifuse ~/iPhone --root "**No device found**"

No relevant topics here in stackoverflow and indeed this lib does not get much attention elsewhere. Another person on reddit same issue but no replies to his question.

Ubuntu 18.04 with extended service (Pro)
iPhone 16.5.1

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion (really a work-around):
I successfully move files back and forth from my iPhone 8, iOS 16.7.2 over my home WiFi network, with the app "File Manager Pro" by zuhanden, using lftp on my Linux laptop. I had to download lftp. I don't know if this can also be done on any other of the file manager apps available.

1. open File Manager, then, on Home page, select "Add connection" (blue highlight on my Iphone). Select WiFi Connect, then "Enable". The local IP will be displayed.
2. Open Terminal. cd to directory file(s) reside. Then, "lftp". Then "put -O http://[ip address for File Manager connection] [filename]". That's upper case letter O.

lftp also includes a "get" command.

Good luck!